# how can i can make a section sticky on swipepages?

Tags: html, css, sticky, sticky-footer

can anyone help me to make a sticky section which will be like this https://stonescorner.denta.com.au/ (mobile version) example site. i would like to create a same section with 2 buttons on swipepages.com but i am not sure what would be right custom css and html to use on the site to make something like this. anyone could help me on that. have a great day!

Regards
Jahidul

i would like to create a same section with 2 buttons on swipepages.com but i am not sure what would be right custom css and html to use on the site to make something like this.

Comment: can you share the code or file that you are working on. we cannot help you if we are unable to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the positions property of CSS. Either position fixed or sticky.